# firebase data not being updated with use effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hi i have to refresh my page to see the effect of the person adding an event to the calendar:

my code is

```js
const handleDateClick = async (DateClickArg) => {
  if (DateClickArg) {
    const title = prompt("Enter title", DateClickArg.dateStr); // allows user to put a title in

    // making object
    const event = {
      title: title ? title : DateClickArg.dateStr,
      start: DateClickArg.date,
      allDay: true,
    };

    allEvents.push(event);

    const db = fire.firestore();
    let currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const doc = await fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("userCalendar")
      .doc(currentUserUID)
      .get();

    db.collection("userCal/" + currentUserUID + "/activities").add({ event });
  }
};
```

and my getuserinfo is:

```js
const getUserInfo = async () => {
  let currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;

  const qSnap = await fire
    .firestore()
    .collection("userCal")
    .doc(currentUserUID)
    .collection("activities")
    .get();

  const data = [];
  data = qSnap.docs.map((d) => ({
    id: d.id,
    title: d.data().event.title,
    start: d.data().event.start.toDate(),
    allDay: d.data().event.allDay,
    ...d.data(),
  }));

  //setData(data)
  console.log(data);
  setData([...data]);
};

useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = false;

  if (!mounted) {
    getUserInfo();
  }

  return () => {
    mounted = true;
  };
}, []);
```

where am i going wrong with my use effect? is there a way for the data to update in the browser once its added to firebase? i am using react full calendar

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `mounted` variable in your effect hook? Doesn't seem to do anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Using `get()` only returns a point-in-time snapshot of your data. If you want to listen for [realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), use `.onSnapshot()` instead.

You'll also need to make sure you unsubscribe from updates when your component is cleaned up

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;

  return fire
    .firestore()
    .collection("userCal")
    .doc(currentUserUID)
    .collection("activities")
    .onSnapshot(({ docs }) => {
      setData(
        docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            title: data.event.title,
            start: data.event.start.toDate(),
            allDay: data.event.allDay,
            ...data,
          };
        })
      );
    });
}, []);
```

`.onShapshot()` returns an *unsubscribe* function so returning that from your effect hook will run it when your component is unmounted.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your firebase call is ok, there is an error inside your `useEffect` call. You are setting the mounted variable wrong, it is supposed to be false when your component is destroyed and true after your component is rendered. Also, to avoid unexpected behaviors I highly recommend using the `useRef` hook to check that.

```
function Component() {
  const isMounted = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;

    if (isMounted) {
      getUserInfo();
    }

    return () => { isMounted.current = false }
  }, []);

  ...
}

export default Component;
```